# Why does the Batmobile have RPG?

Tags: the-dark-knight, batman-begins

Why does Batmobile in the Dark Knight trilogy have a missile shooting feature? Batman believes in no use of guns, is the rule exceptional for the batmobile?

Comment: This is not the first time in the movies that the Batmobile has included missiles.

Comment: RPGs do not have to kill someone in order to be effective and/or useful.  On the flipside, there's not much you can realistically do with a gun that doesn't involve shooting someone.

Comment: IIRC, the vehicle was designed for military purposes, so it came with it and was not requested by Batman.

Comment: "Batman believes in no use of guns" according to who?

Comment: Batman 1989, he has high explosives on his wheels, Twin forward mounted Browning machine guns, and the game for the movie had rocket launchers. The Batmobile has always been fully loaded.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Combination of things here.  First, as @DustinDavis mentions above, this wasn't "designed" for Batman and the capabilities were already on the vehicle.  Despite the fact he modifies each vehicle from its military design, Batman probably saw use for the feature and kept it.

Going off of that, Batman does not use the missile feature on people, he instead uses it to break through buildings/walls/etc. so that he can get to where he needs to be.

The capability is also featured in *The Dark Knight Rises*, as seen towards the end when he uses the missile feature to punch a hole through a building essentially so he can fly the bomb outside the city limits.

Simply, Batman's a crafty guy and uses the missiles for practical, not violent purposes.